# Why does my regular expression in Python not capture integers?

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regular expression to find sequences of numbers that aren't refixed with `0x`.

eg.

```
0
50505
20201
0012
```

My regular expression is `(?:[^(0x)]\d+)`, which (in my head) translates to match any sequence of digits not started with `0x`. But this doesn't work - what assumption am I incorrectly making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[^(0x)]` in your regular expression match any character that is not `(`, `0`, `x`, `)`.

Use negative lookbehind:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!0x)\d+\b', '0 0x111 50505 20201 0012')
['0', '11', '50505', '20201', '0012']
```

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

> (?<!...)
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a
>   match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion. Similar
>   to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must only
>   match strings of some fixed length. Patterns which start with negative
>   lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the string being
>   searched.

---

**UPDATE**

Use following regular expression:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', '0 0x111 50505 20201 0012')
['0', '50505', '20201', '0012']
```

Comment: But I guess the '11' element isnt really wanted?

Comment: @Jahaja, Ah.. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a non-capture group for anything that doesn't start with [0 or x].

Did you try a negative look-behind?

```
(r'(?<!0x)\d+')
```

(Took me a helluva long time to type this on the phone and now I see someone's already sorted it. Lesson learned: no regex on the phone.)

Comment: You get a +1 for being a close second, though.